# Bootstrap Affix not working with IE, Chrome or MS Edge

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have been developing in Firefox and only just noticed after a few days of creating a new site that bootstrap affix does not work in Chrome/IE/Edge? I am using the latest version of Bootstrap and the latest versions of Firefox and Chrome. Not sure what version of IE I am running.

Tried a few work arounds but nothing seems to help.

CSS:

```
.affix {
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.affix + .container-fluid {
    padding-top: 0px;
}
.affix-bottom {
    position: absolute;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myScrollspy" data-offset="20">
    <div id="scroll"> ....
    </div>
    <!--  Navbar -->
    <div id="nav">
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" style="background: #26292E none repeat scroll 0% 0%;border-color: #DE5E60;">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
                <a class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bar"></span>
                </a>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav pull-right navbar-nav">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
                                Sign In
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu form-login stop-propagation" role="menu">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i>
                                        Email address
                                    </label>
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i>
                                        Password
                                    </label>
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password" />
                                </div>
                                <!--<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> Submit</button>-->
                                <a id="contact-submit" class="submit" href="#">Submit</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav pull-right navbar-nav">
                        <li>
                            <form class="navbar-form">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search" type="text" />
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                                </button>
                            </form>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <span class="badge">2</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar -->
    </div>
    <!-- End Navbar -->
```

JS:

```
$('#nav').affix({
    offset: {
        top: $('#scroll').height()
    }
});
```

Comment: I managed to correct this by manually setting the `.affix` selector's `z-index`. I just set it to 9999 and it popped right up. [Here's an updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/611doyyg/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pull up the developer tools in Chrome, you'll notice that the menu is actually affixed to the top of the screen, it just can't be seen.

If you modify your affix selector to specify it's z-index, it should work.

```
.affix {
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100; //100 was the minimum I managed to find to make it work.
}
```

Comment: Much appreciated! Saved the day...!